# ArcPy insertRow asking for a sequence of values

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor

I've got code that pulls the center point from a layer, and places it in a new feature class as part of a more complex analytical process.

I'm trying to get the centroid written to an `in_memory` feature class in order to use as a processing input for other stuff.  There are no fields needed in addition to the `SHAPE@XY` token.  Here's what I've got:

```
def get_extent_centroid(layer):
    desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
    if desc.dataType in ['FeatureLayer', 'RasterLayer']:
        extent = desc.extent
        array = arcpy.Array()
        array.add(extent.lowerLeft)
        array.add(extent.lowerRight)
        array.add(extent.upperRight)
        array.add(extent.upperLeft)
        array.add(extent.lowerLeft)
        pg = arcpy.Polygon(array)
        centroid = pg.centroid
        return centroid


inlyr = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
center = get_extent_centroid(inlyr)
center_fc = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass("in_memory", "layercenter", "POINT", spatial_reference=arcpy.Describe(inlyr).spatialReference)
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(center_fc, 'SHAPE@XY') as cursor:
    cursor.insertRow(center)
```

This results in:

```
TypeError: argument must be sequence of values
```

Which suggests that even though `.centroid` yields a valid point geometry, I have to do something more with it before sending it to the `SHAPE@XY` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, apparently `insertCursor` demands a list object.  With the following, the code works.  I'll leave it here for posterity; if mods want to remove the question in case they find it too basic, that's fine too.

```
def get_extent_centroid(layer):
desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
if desc.dataType in ['FeatureLayer', 'RasterLayer']:
    extent = desc.extent
    array = arcpy.Array()
    array.add(extent.lowerLeft)
    array.add(extent.lowerRight)
    array.add(extent.upperRight)
    array.add(extent.upperLeft)
    array.add(extent.lowerLeft)
    pg = arcpy.Polygon(array)
    centroid = pg.centroid
    return centroid


inlyr = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
center = get_extent_centroid(inlyr)
center_fc = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass("in_memory", "layercenter", "POINT", spatial_reference=arcpy.Describe(inlyr).spatialReference)

# fixed part
center_row = [(center.Y, center.X)]

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(center_fc, 'SHAPE@XY') as cursor:
cursor.insertRow(center_row)
```

Comment: But first you ought to capture that SpatialReference in a variable, and pass it into the Polygon constructor. While optional, failure to pass in a spatial reference can corrupt your coordinates, and possibly the geometry itself, but only when it is rewritten to conform to the target SpatialReference, during the `insertRow`.

Comment: Not that [FeatureToPoint](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-point.htm) would do this faster.

Comment: Accept your answer, one less unanswered question